# Listar aniversariantes do dia usando Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Eu uso o código abaixo que me dá uma lista de aniversariantes por mês, mas precisaria para a data atual.
Exemplo: hoje dia 09/04 e a exibição da lista.

```
$aniversariantesDoMes = Pessoa::whereMonth('dt_nasc', Carbon::now()->month)
            ->orderByRaw('day(dt_nasc) asc')->get();
```

$aniversariantesDoDia = **(como eu faria?)**

Deve ser algo simples, mas não consegui mesmo.

Comment: `whereDate` no lugar de `whereMonth`?

Comment: Já tentei com whereDate , aí me retorna uma lista vazia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que pude entender, você quer só o dia e o mês de qualquer data, então, pode chamar os dois métodos correspondentes

- `whereDay`
- `whereMonth`

Exemplo:

```
$dataAtualCarbon = Carbon::now();

$aniversariantesDoMes = Pessoa::whereMonth('dt_nasc', $dataAtualCarbon->month)
    ->whereDay('dt_nasc', $dataAtualCarbon->day)
    ->orderByRaw('day(dt_nasc) asc')->get();
```

essa maneira com `Builder` vai servir para qualquer banco de dados que o [Framework Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) está disponível.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo. Era exatamente isso. Eu estava passando apenas 1 parametro . Entendi , muito obrigado

Comment: se for a resposta da sua pergunta @CarlosFarias assinale como resposta...

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do Virgilio já deve resolver o seu problema, mas vou deixar a minha resposta com um pequeno diferencial que talvez você precise. Vamos supor que você precise listar os aniversariantes do mês e do dia na mesma função. Então você pode fazer isso utilizando a função `when` do Laravel. Assim se você não passar o parâmetro do aniversariantes do dia, ele vai listar apenas o do mês.

```
// Você pegará o parâmetro da sua request
$aniversariantesDoDia = $request->input( 'aniversariantesDoDia', null);

$aniversariantesDoMes = Pessoa::whereMonth('dt_nasc', Carbon::now()->month)
            ->when( $aniversariantesDoDia, function ( $query ) use ( $aniversariantesDoDia ) {
                return $query->whereDay( 'dt_nasc', $aniversariantesDoDia );
            })
            ->orderByRaw('day(dt_nasc) asc')->get();
```

Comment: Realmente poderá ser muito util, grato!

Comment: Vamos lá: em vez de escrever `$aniversariantesDoDia = $request->input( 'aniversariantesDoDia' ) ? $request->input( 'aniversariantesDoDia' ) : null;` só precisa fazer assim: `$aniversariantesDoDia = $request->input( 'aniversariantesDoDia' );` automáticamente é `null` pelo valor padrão ou `$aniversariantesDoDia = $request->input( 'aniversariantesDoDia', null);` para explicitar o seu valor padrão ... que já é `null` só como exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado @VirgilioNovic não sabia que o valor default era null. Vou editar aqui